# Where to put CSS from CSS Animation Maker

Tags: html, css, animation

I used an CSS (and other code animation maker) called Fabula to make a simple animation for my website. Does anyone know how I can get my animation on my website? I'm stuck and I've been trying to figure out how all day, as it's something I've never once had to do. I'm still quite new to HTML and CSS.

The Code for the Animation:

````
-moz-animation: scale 5.0s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1.0, 0.22, 1.0);
-o-animation: scale 5.0s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1.0, 0.22, 1.0);
animation: scale 5.0s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1.0, 0.22, 1.0);
@keyframes scale {
    100% {
      transform: scale(3, 3);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Although you provided the CSS, you will need to include more information like how you want to actually use the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the -o- vendor prefix. Here is the updated code. You can test it right here from your browser.

```css
.animation-class {
  animation: scale 5.0s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1.0, 0.22, 1.0);
  -moz-animation: scale 5.0s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1.0, 0.22, 1.0);
  -webkit-animation: scale 5.0s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1.0, 0.22, 1.0);
}


/** Keyframe here **/

@keyframes scale {
  100% {
    transform: scale(3, 3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-class">...anything goes here</div>
```

That should be all.

Comment: Actually `o-` is real, it's the old pre-WebKit versions of Opera.

Comment: @imvain2 Yeah you're right. But he shouldn't use it anymore

Comment: @imvain2 that's like 2013 if I'm correct? There is accessibility, and "accessibility". I don't think it's still relevant.

Comment: I was just commenting on the part where the answer said it isn't a thing, not that it was old.

Comment: @imvain2 true. I guess what I really wanted to say is more "Planning support for pre-WebKit versions of Opera (~2013) is not required anymore, in my opinion".